# C# program on low ram - backgroundworker not completing DoWork task before ending

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, ram

I am currently trying to run a web bot written in C# (web requests) on a VPS that has a i7 processor, 512 mb ram, and runs w7 ultimate. The program uses a background worker to complete the main work to not freeze up the GUI.

However, whenever I try running the program, it ends unexpectedly (displays the message that I have for my bgw workcompleted event) without running through the main part of the program.

Is the 512 mb ram way too low to be able to run this program? It's near the max % usage when I try to run it. My own computer can run the bot on it's own fine. The bot takes user input from three richtextboxes and stores them into string arrays, each one having around ~3k entries.

My dowork code:

```
 private void mainWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        var values = (UserInputData)e.Argument;
        int submits = 0;
        string[] emaillist = values.emails;
        string[] addresses = values.addys;
        string[] allname = values.names;
        int addresscount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < emaillist.Length; i++)
        {
            string emailAddress = emaillist[i];
            string addy = addresses[addresscount];
            string[] addysplit = addy.Split('|');
            string street = addysplit[0];
            string city = addysplit[1];
            string state = addysplit[2].Substring(0, 2);
            string zip = addysplit[3];
            string name = allname[i];
            string[] namesplit = name.Split('|');
            string fname = namesplit[0];
            string lname = namesplit[1];

            mainWorker.ReportProgress(1, emailAddress);
            HttpSession submit = new HttpSession();
            submit.setUserAgent();
            submit.getPage("");

            string postDataEmail = "...";

            if (submit.html.Contains(".."))
            {
                submits++;
                mainWorker.ReportProgress(90, submits.ToString());
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                mainWorker.ReportProgress(50);
                Image captchaImg = getImage(captchaUrl);


                string postdata = "...";

                submit.postPage("...", postdata);

                if (submit.html.Contains("..."))
                {
                    submits++;
                    saveToTextFile("submitted emails", emailAddress);
                    saveToTextFile("info", emailAddress + ":" + addy + ":" + name);
                    mainWorker.ReportProgress(90, submits.ToString());

                }
                else if (submit.html.Contains("Enter code in field"))
                {
                    mainWorker.ReportProgress(80);
                    decap.reportBadCaptcha();
                    i--;
                    addresscount++;
                    continue;
                }


                addresscount++;
            }
        }
    }
```

emaillist array is populated from a richtextbox of values.
My reportprogress event handlers print a message to the gui to let me know where I am during execution. Running through the for loop will display at least one message all times.

Code runs fine and executes normally on my own computer. Running this on the server I mentioned does something I can't seem to wrap my head around.

Comment: If it were a memory issue, you'd get an `OutOfMemoryException`.

Comment: That's what I figured... but the program doesn't crash. Running the same values on my computer is fine, however when trying to run it on this server it seemingly skips all of the code in my bgw dowork method.

Comment: Hard to guess without seeing any code...

Comment: A standard bug is to forget to check the e.Error property in the RunWorkerCompleted event handler.  Which tells you what exception caused DoWork() to terminate prematurely.

Comment: Oh... the error is reported in e.Error property? I had no idea. I'm guessing the outofmemory exception is saved there.

Comment: If it was an outofmemory exception the process would terminate as it is a state corrupted exception...

Comment: It's possible that you don't clean up your memory properly. Especially, check if the `HttpSession` object can be Disposed, also if opening Files (inside your `saveToTextFile` method) there is potential to forget to `Dispose()`

Answer (score 0):

By the sounds of it I think this is a thread management issue. Your i7 should have 12 threads available, priorities and the load on the workstation may be affecting how this is executing. Try out [threadpool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as.aspx) and keep the program running until execution is complete